# Android animation. Two translate activity

Tags: android, android-animation

I want to create animation with two actions. First action: view go forward, second action: view go back. I create xml for describe animation, but it doesn't work. Thank you for your attention. My **/anim/move_animation.xml**:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator">
          <translate
           android:fromYDelta="50%" 
           android:toYDelta="50%"
           android:fromXDelta="0%" 
           android:toXDelta="50%"
           android:duration="2000" />
        <translate
           android:startOffset="2000"
           android:fromYDelta="50%" 
           android:toYDelta="50%"
           android:fromXDelta="50%" 
           android:toXDelta="0%"
           android:duration="2000" />
    </set>
```

**Activity:**

```
public class TestActivity extends Activity {
    private LinearLayout LL;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        LL = (LinearLayout) this.findViewById(R.id.MainLayout);

        Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.move_animation);
        LL.startAnimation(anim);
    }
}
```

**Layout:**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/MainLayout" >
     <ImageView
          android:id="@+id/Icon"
          android:layout_width="30dp"
          android:layout_height="30dp"
          android:background="@drawable/icon" >
      </ImageView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: what doesn't work about it. You're probably going to need to elaborate more if you expect us to be able to help.

Comment: do two different animations, run them after each other, if still your problem occurs, it means there is problem with the way you doing the animation.

Comment: @Tim Thank you for your comment. I special create test small project for resolve this problem. I added other files to the topic.

Comment: @HeshamSaeed yes, i except that view move forward and than go back, but at first time i view is invisible and after 4 or 6 secons view will show at start position(0,0).

Comment: Please elaborate more, of what you are getting and what you really want to do, specific explanation (what do you mean by go forward? You want to move the image or the whole layout?)

Comment: Are you trying to animate a whole activity? Something like this: http://blog.blundell-apps.com/animate-an-activity/

Comment: I think the answer to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4482261/how-to-run-translate-animation-sequentially will help you.

Answer (score 0):

make 2 animations of you animation.
first will be first translate and second animation will be your second translate.
and you setonanimationlistener and onanimationend in it. when first will end you nned to start second. it will work nice