# Sequential animation of nested sets

Tags: android, android-animation

I am currently working on an Android splash screen animation. Google's [documentation for animation resources](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource) states that `<set>` has an attribute `android:ordering`, which *"specifies the play ordering of animations in this set"*. There are two (self-explanatory) options:

- `sequentially`
- `together` (default)

The animation.xml below shows a small implementation, but the way it's being executed differs from what I expected. The nested sets are all executed at the same time, although I defined `android:ordering="sequentially"` for their parent. I expected only the contents of each nested set to be shown simulatneous. Does the ordering attribute of the parent set not affect nested sets?

I am aware of the solution proposed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4482261/how-to-run-several-translate-animations-sequentially), but I don't see the reason why my definition of a sequential execution of animations should not work just as well.

**animation.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:ordering="sequentially">
    <set>
        <alpha
            android:duration="400"
            android:fromAlpha="0"
            android:interpolator="@anim/interpolator"
            android:toAlpha="0.4" />
        <scale
            android:duration="400"
            android:fromXScale="0"
            android:fromYScale="0"
            android:interpolator="@anim/interpolator"
            android:pivotX="30%"
            android:pivotY="50%"
            android:toXScale="0.4"
            android:toYScale="0.4" />
    </set>
    <set>
        <alpha
            android:duration="200"
            android:fromAlpha="0.4"
            android:toAlpha="0.3" />
        <scale
            android:duration="200"
            android:fromXScale="0.4"
            android:fromYScale="0.4"
            android:pivotX="30%"
            android:pivotY="50%"
            android:toXScale="0.3"
            android:toYScale="0.3" />
    </set>
</set>
```

Comment: What happens if you set `android:ordering="sequentially"` for your nested sets too?

Comment: @algrid that does not change anything

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no `ordering` attribute on a *view animation* set.

I think you are confusing [property animation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource#Property) (defined as `res/animator/...` resources) and [view animation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource#View) (in `res/anim/...`).

Both can have a `<set>` element, but the syntax is different. For a *property animation*, it's :

```
<set
  android:ordering=["together" | "sequentially"]>
...
```

and it creates an [`AnimatorSet`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/AnimatorSet)

while for a *view animation*, it's :

```
<set
    android:interpolator="@[package:]anim/interpolator_resource"
    android:shareInterpolator=["true" | "false"] >
...
```

which creates an [`AnimationSet`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/AnimationSet)

Comment: Thank you very much, I was missing this part completely. I still think it would be nice to have the ordering attribute for both, but at least my question was answered now.