# How do I add a bounce animation with easing?

Tags: java, android

I want to add animate a linearlayout to vertically going up and then easing to it's original position. Like in [this](https://youtu.be/x0Z0jVFfK1M?t=3). However, I only know how to have the linearlayout go up without the easing.

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate
        android:duration="800"
        android:fromYDelta="50%p"
        />
</set>
```

This is the animation xml file that I added for vertically going up.

Comment: If you know how to use external libraries, then check out [Yoyo](https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidViewAnimations)

Answer (score 0):

You should use `overshoot_interpolator`,

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:interpolator="@android:anim/overshoot_interpolator">
    <translate
            android:duration="800"
            android:fromYDelta="50%p"
    />
</set>
```

If you want more customization, you could run multiple translate animations in sequence. You could use [android:startOffset](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.html#attr_android:startOffset) to delay the animations and run them 'sequentially'. ([Example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4482261/11016588))